# select into and add to current value of variable in stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get sum of number of records in two tables in a variable. Following is the code:

```
declare v_sum int default 0;
declare v_count2 int default 0;

select count(*) into v_sum
from table1;

select count(*) into v_count2 
from table2;

set v_sum = v_sum + v_count2;
```

Is there any way to directly select and add the table2 count in `v_sum` without creating `v_count2` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two variables. One way is to combine both sets and then do `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO v_sum
FROM (SELECT 1 AS c
 FROM table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1
 FROM table2) AS sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT SUM(c)
INTO v_sum
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c
     FROM table1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM table2) AS sub
```

Comment: Should I use this if tables contains millions of records? or write separate queries would be better?

Comment: @ctor Compare both solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query directly, e.g.:

```
SET v_sum = v_sum + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid variable could be:

```
select v_sum + count(*) into v_sum
from table2;
```